# Доработать форму для отправки сообщения на jQuery без submit(html)

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="Имя:" onfocus="if(this.value =='Имя:' ) this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Имя:'" />
                <input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail:" onfocus="if(this.value =='E-mail:' ) this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail:'" />
                <textarea name="message" onfocus="if(this.value =='Сообщение:' ) this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Сообщение:'">Сообщение:</textarea>
                <a href="">ОТПРАВИТЬ</a>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a class="formSubmit" href="#">ОТПРАВИТЬ</a>

$('.formSubmit').on('click', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().submit();

});
```